# How to keep the application running during a breakpoint?

Tags: java

When testing/debugging a Java application, how one could put a breakpoint somewhere that get's caught and does not hang the whole application?

I have a simple Spring Boot application, and when I set a breakpoint somewhere in my IntelliJ Community IDE, the whole app hangs.

How can I allow the app to run even though I am holding one thread?

Could I get 2 breakpoints at the same time from 2 users trying to login at the same time?

Comment: Your IDE should have an option in the breakpoint settings to pause all threads or just the affected thread. I know at least IDEA and Eclipse both provide this option. If you don't want the affected thread to pause either, then you don't really want a breakpoint, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rightclick on the breakpoint in Intellij you can select suspent from "all" to "Thread" so only the current thread stops and your application should keep running.